# Cannot convert value of type '(User?, _) -> ()' to expected argument type.i am struggling to resolve that error

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication

[image]

Hey guys i am struggling to resolve this error actually i am trying to send these 4 strings and one picture to firebase and this was working fine until this error came up.
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text else {
            print("Form is not valid")
            return
        }

```
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user:User?, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        guard let uid = user?.uid else {
            return
        }

        //successfully authenticated user
        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).jpg")

        if let profileImage = self.profileImageView.image, let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.1) {
```

//            if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!) {

```
            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }

                if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

                    let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]

                    self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
                }
            })
        }
    })
}

fileprivate func registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(_ uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)

    usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

        if err != nil {
            print(err!)
            return
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris for the kind advice.i will post the code from next time and your command really helped me in understanding the problem.

Comment: You can and should edit this question to include the code as described in comments above. You don’t have to wait until your next question, editing exists for a reason, you can still improve this question.

Comment: thanks David edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a type of user parameter (user: User?) you also have to write the types of other parameters (error: Error?)

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user: User?, error: Error?)
   in ...
}
```

Also you may write by this way:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in   
   ...
}
```